# What's the best way to adapt different data types between insert/select from MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb-.net-driver

I think I am missing a simple solution here. When I run a select (using Linq-style on IQueryable) that returns IQueryable, I may want MyClass to return differently-formatted key/values than I will use in my insert.

Consider as example the below UploadFile class and note properties id and Filetimestamp. When I SET Filetimestamp I want it stored as DateTime, but when I RETRIEVE IQueryable I would like to:

1. See Filetimestamp returned as String
   OR
2. See a separate property returned as String reflecting Filetimestamp.toString(). This property doesn't have a corresponding key in the database; it's just a decoration of a real key/value from BSON.

Thinking #1 was unlikely, I pursued #2 by adding a get-only field Filetimestamp_str that returns Filetimestamp.toString(). When I select, behavior is as expected. When I insert, I see failures.

I could create a decorator class that I use for gets and all would work - but am I missing something more fundamental and simple here?

```
public class UploadFile : IUploadFile
{
    public Object _id { get; set; }
    public String Filepath { get; set; }
    public String Filename { get; set; }
    public String Filetype { get; set; }
    public String Fileauthor { get; set; }
    public DateTime Filetimestamp { get; set; }
    public Object FileID { get; set; }

    // these keys are not in DB 
    public String Filetimestamp_str { get { return Filetimestamp.ToString(); } } 
    public String _id_str { get { return _id.ToString();  } }
}
```

Comment: Could you show us an error you see on insert? This error the main question?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a BsonClassMap, specifying which properties should (not) be serialized. See the [Serialization Tutorial](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Serialization+Tutorial). However, according to that tutorial, a read-only property should not be automapped, so I should not expect errors on the insert.